# PL/SQL can't put value into index by table

Tags: indexing, plsql, insert

I can't put my value of `v_emp` into my `emp_table`.
It is all going wrong at this line:

```
emp_table(counter) := v_emp;
```

The error that I get is:

> invalid use of type name of subtype name

I can't see what the problem is..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE laatste_emp IS
    v_emp   employees%ROWTYPE;
    TYPE emp_table is table of 
    employees%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    counter NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    select * into v_emp
    from employees
    where hire_date =
    (select max(hire_date) from employees);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_emp.employee_id || ' ' || v_emp.last_name || ' ' || v_emp.hire_date);
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        FOR i in 100 .. 206 LOOP
            select * into v_emp
            from employees 
            where employee_id = i
            and hire_date = (select max(hire_date) from employees);
            IF SQL%FOUND THEN
                emp_table(counter) := v_emp;
                counter := counter + 1;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TYPE emp_table is table of employees%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;` only declares a type, not an actual variable you can write into. You need to add the variable too:

```
TYPE emp_table_type is table of employees%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
emp_table emp_table_type;
```

Please note I added "_type" suffix into your definition.